# How can you convert a 2 dimensional array into a 1 dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to know how to convert a 2 dimensional array into a 1 dimensional array. I have come up with some code but it doesn't exactly seem to work. Can someone please help me? Thanks.

```
public class TESTER1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    static String[][] data = new String[][] {{"Dum","Dumer","Dumbest"}};

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        convertData(data);
    }

    public static void convertData(String[][]data) {
        String[] toReturn = new String[data.length];
        for(int i = 0;i<data.length;i++) {
            for(int j = 0;j<3;j++){
                toReturn[i] = data[i][j];
            }
        }
        for(String s:toReturn) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

[edit]Thank you very much. Is it possible to convert each row in the String[][] into
a index in a String[] for example if we convert the String[][] (above code), then when
i print out array[0] it should print out dum,dummer,dumbest [edit]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public static String[] flatten(String[][] data) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++){
            list.add(data[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Or add whole rows at one time:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        list.addAll( Arrays.asList(data[i]) );
    }
```

**Edit:**
From comments on my answer it seems like this is what the OP wanted (i.e. converting each row of 2d array to some string representation of it):

```
public static String[] rowsToString(String[][] data) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        String row = Arrays.toString(data[i]);
        list.add( row.substring(1, row.length()-1) );
    }

    return list.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: This is only one of possible ways. It could be even simplier at the cost of memory or more complicated but more efficient.

Comment: thank you very much, i have one question though.. How can i change it so that each row is equal to a index in the String[]?

Comment: Glad to help. What do you mean by row is equal to index? Row cannot be equal to index...

Comment: When I say the row is equal to the index, i mean to say is that take the all the information from on row and add it to one index, like the above code get each element and adds to the array, i want the row to be added not each element.

Comment: Like what i'm saying is that, like when i run it, it returns the elements seprately, each element belongs to a different index in the array. I want it so that when it prints out ray[0] it returns dum,dummer,dumbest on in one string.

Comment: I see now. Hm, you should edit your question then, it is not clear that this is what you want.

Comment: i'm very sorry, can you still please help me though?

Comment: Thank you so much! Thank you very very much. Sorry, i have tendenacy of asking more than one question =) What is the best possible way to improve your java code? and also to improve your logic? If you could this it would be just the cherry on top =) Thank you so much.

Comment: no not the code itself, i am saying code in general like some tips i can use to improve other code that i write.

Answer (score 2):

The length of the 1-dimensional array must be the sums of the lengths of all rows in the 2-dimensional array. Of course, Java doesn't really have "true" 2-dimensional arrays, but arrays of arrays. This code works, and is wrapped in a simple demo program.

public class ArrayFlattening {

```
public static final String[][] STRINGS2 = {
    {"my", "dog", "has", "fleas"},
    {"how", "now", "brown", "cow"},
    {"short", "row"},
    {"this", "is", "a", "final", "row", "in", "this", "test"},
};

public static String[] flatten(String[][] a2) {
    String[] result = new String[totalSize(a2)];
    int index = 0;
    for (String[] a1 : a2) {
        for (String s : a1) {
            result[index++] = s;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static int totalSize(String[][] a2) {
    int result = 0;
    for (String[] a1 : a2) {
        result += a1.length;
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("" + STRINGS2.length + " rows");
    for (String[] strings1 : STRINGS2) {
        System.out.println("" + strings1.length + " strings");
        for (String s : strings1) {
            System.out.print("\t" + s);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    String[] strings1 = flatten(STRINGS2);
    System.out.println(strings1.length + " strings");
    for (String s : strings1) {
        System.out.print("\t" + s);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Comment: Hey, Joel. Stuck in SF without my Knuth. Is there a generalization (even a Theorem) that you're aware of? I'm trying to project from 2-dimensions into 1 in a reversible and memory efficient manner. I have the advantage of starting with a pre-ordained size. Perhaps this deserves another post...

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner version:

```
public static String[] flatten(String[][] data) {
    List<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String[] sublist : Arrays.asList(data)) {
        for (String elem : sublist) {
            toReturn.add(elem);
        }
    }
    return toReturn.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatten did become much easier in Java 8 with the stream API. The function can be expressed as:

```
private static String[] flatten(String[][] data) {
    return Stream.of(data).flatMap(Stream::of).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```